# Making a rectangle with "Squircle" corners in GLSL

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader, rounded-corners

I need to make a shader that rounds the corners with the "squircle" rounding, but without taking the whole rectangle into account. When doing a normal squircle shader, you bake in the width and the length of the square. But since I want to do this on a rectangle, I don't want the corners looking "stretched out" depending on the ratio.

Currently I have this:

```
float squircle( in vec2 p, in vec2 b, in float r ) 
{   
    vec2 q = abs(p)-b+r;
    float power = 4.0;
    q = max(q, 0.0);
    return (pow(q.x, power) + pow(q.y, power) - pow(r, power)) / pow(r, 10.0);
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 p = (2.0*fragCoord-iResolution.xy)/iResolution.y;

    vec2 si = vec2(1.3,0.7);
    vec4 ra = 0.3 + 0.3*cos( 2.0*iTime + vec4(0,1,2,3) );

    float d = squircle( p, si, ra.x );
    
    fragColor = vec4(d, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

But the issue is that I don't fully understand why `/ pow(r, 10.0)` made it smooth and not animated, and I don't know how to actually smooth the edges. They are currently only smooth at some points of this animation. The higher the value I divide by, the less "fussiness" and animation there will be.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just an optical illusion? 
`vec2 q = abs(p)-b+r;` `q = max(q, 0.0);` calculates the distance from the fragment to the center of a circle with radius `r` in the corner of the rectangle.
This is independent of the aspect ratio of the rectangle. 
The aspect ratio of the viewport is taken into account because in `p = (2.0*fragCoord-iResolution.xy)/iResolution.y;` is divided by `iResolution.y` instead of `iResolution.xy`.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. What would be an  optical illusion?

Comment: You said '"When doing a normal squircle shader, you bake in the width and the length of the square."* - I think you are wrong. I think this is just a visual effect, not a measurable effect caused by the aspect ratio of the rectangle

Comment: Nope, this is what happened everytime I tried it. I never managed to not get it to look squished. If you know how to, I would love to see a solution <3

Comment: And most importantly, I would like to be able to control the radius of how far in on the corners that should be rounded like this, if that makes sense. I wouldn't want the whole thing to be rounded, since then it would look different on different sized objects.

Comment: I think we're talking past each other. I probably don't understand your question correctly. Can you add a sketch or screenshot explaining what you mean? A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: What about creating single channel `mask` texture with rounded corners? You could use this to modulate the output of the fragment shader. Create an anti-aliased texture 'offline', and `glGenerateMipmap` to create the MIP levels. Also, you get sampling / scaling of the rounded rect for free, using hardware texture sampling. I have a useful piece of code for this if you're interested, with 'border' and corner 'radius' args to generate the anti-aliased texture.

Comment: @BrettHale oh that sounds amazing actually! Do you have it online somewhere?

Comment: @chikuba - I'll post this modified 'snippet' as an answer, even if it is ~ 170 lines!